# how to figure out all messages with a specific groupId has been read from the queue in SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, distributed-system

Here is my requirement: I receive a request to validate some data/records. Records would be sent to the SQS queue per each request for further processing by another service/component. The message structure looks like this:

```
messageId: //a unique message id
requestId: //request id common between all messages/records for that request
record_body: {//key-value pairs}
```

Everything works fine. Now I want to figure out when all messages with the same request id have been read from the queue (I.e. there is no more message for that request id). 
The idea that I have is to write each message/record to the database upon each read and then have another scheduled service that can be triggered (by cloudwatch) to check the number of records for each request and finally update the status of the request to complete if the number of records in the database are equal to the number of records in the original request.
I just want to share this to see if anybody else had this kind of requirement and how they approached it!

Comment: If you want complete accuracy, you'll need to keep track of in/out count per group in an [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) database way. If you go that route, and your messages are small, it might be cost-effective to eliminate SQS and just use the database as your message queue.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

Include the number of requests and current request to the queue. Make sure the request goes to the queue in the same order.

Example - You have 4 requests for requestId - **abc**

You will send each request with values included **(1:4) (2:4) (3:4) (4:4)** in the order to the queue.

This way when you are reading from the queue you will read (4:4) last and you will know you have processed all the 4.

Another way to do is include total number of requests in the message in every message and while processing each message check whether it matches the original one as you have total in your message now. (by querying the database).

Comment: Your solution would work if I have a FIFO SQS queue. But in my project I have to use Standard SQS queue because the records are being send to the SQS through the SNS and SNS cannot send the messages to a FIFO Queue.